# Preposition "into" with manufacture: "To produce high-quality plants to manufacture _into_ the range of teas that.."

Tags: prepositions

I am trying to fully understand the meaning of the preposition "into" in the below context so I can write a sentence like this.

> *But these countries have to have the right climate and geographical features If they are going to produce sufficient high-quality plants to **manufacture into the wide range of teas** that are exported around the world.*

I would have written like this:

*manufacture the wide range of teas*

But I am not sure that whether it is grammatically correct or not. Is this preposition "into" often used with the sentence like "wide range of"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Into* is not unusual with verbs which involve some sort of transformation. The basic 'template' is

> *VERB Substance1 **into** Substance2*

For instance:

- A wicked witch changed<sup>Vb</sup> the princess<sup>s1</sup> **into** a toad<sup>s2</sup>.
- Renaissance alchemists hoped to discover a process for turning<sup>Vb</sup> lead<sup>s1</sup> **into** gold<sup>s2</sup>.
- Gates and Allen built<sup>Vb</sup> their little two-man coding operation<sup>s1</sup> **into** the dominant force<sup>s2</sup> in the emerging microcomputer market.

With *manufacture* as *VERB*, the sense of your sentence is that *tea plants*, Substance1, a raw material, are transformed by the manufacturing process into the *wide range of teas*, Substance2.

> If they have enough high-quality plants they will be able to manufacture them **into** the wide range of teas that are exported around the world.

Note that *plants* here means vegetable organisms, not manufacturing facilities.